# C# Select text between caret and end of the document in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, range, selection, caret

I'm trying to get the program to select all the text between caret and end of the document in Word.
It should be something like:

```
app.ActiveDocument.Range(Selection, EndOdDocument).Select();
```

where **Selection** is supposed to be the caret position, and **EndOfDocument**  - the end of the document.
However, after hours of trying, I can't solve this, although the solution is probably something very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like:

```
app.Selection.End = app.ActiveDocument.Content.End;
```

but, no need to change the selection to get the text:

```
var doc = app.ActiveDocument;
string text = doc.Range(app.Selection.Start, doc.Content.End).Text;
```

Comment: Omg, I knew it was something obvious! Thanks!